# Cursor to log id column value in activity

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-cursor

How do I loop to get `id` column values from `users` table, where "id" generated through :

```
id integer primary key autoincrement
```

I have records like this in my table:

```
id     name

1       Me

2      You
```

Here is what i think i should try:

```
public String[] getUsersId() {

    String selectQuery = "SELECT id FROM " + TABLE_USERS;
          SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
             String[] data = null;

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    db.close();
    return data;
}
```

Now, I would like to know how can I log all the "id" in my activity ?

Comment: simply use `DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor`, the question is: what do you want to return in `getUsersId` method (and why)? what do you want to do with that String[] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `cursor.getInt` to get `int` value from Cursor:

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
             int id_row=cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"));
             //int id_row=cursor.getInt(0);
             Log.d("TAG","id is ::"+id_row);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I have ticked your answer as helpful and will accept in 3 minutes, but still i have a doubt to perform further actions i have to use cursor in my activity itself, right now i am doing like this only : dh.getUsersId();

Comment: @Sophie: please use a data structure for getting data in Activity like ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

You can try in this way

```
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) 
    {
        do
        {
            int idIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("id");
            if ( ideIndex != -1)
            {
                int ID = cursor.getInt(idIndex);
            }
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

**Please check this condition, if your cursor.getCount>0**

```
if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                do {
                    String strId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("yourid");

                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
```